# Perl SFTP really really slow

Tags: perl, ssh, sftp

I'm using the perl Net:SSH2 library to do SFTP. It works well enough but is super slow. It starts off being 7x slower than the link speed (something I could handle) but pretty much as soon as it has transferred 2MB of data it drops to being 1000x slower. Here's a cut down version of my code. I used this Linux command to create a 10M file of random data `dd if=/dev/urandom of=10M.dat bs=1M count=10`. For anyone who would like to run the code please enter details for server, user, password etc.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Fcntl ('O_WRONLY', 'O_CREAT');
use Net::SSH2;
use Time::HiRes qw(gettimeofday);

my $server = 'myserver';
my $username = 'myusername';
my $password = 'mypassword';
my $remoteFile = 'delme.dat';
my $localFile = '10M.dat';

my $ssh = Net::SSH2->new();
$ssh->connect($server) or die('Failed to connect to remote server for sftp');
$ssh->auth_password($username, $password);
$ssh->auth_ok() or die('Invalid username or password');
my $sftp = $ssh->sftp() or die('Ahhh!!');
open(my $localHandle, '<', $localFile) or die($!);
my $remoteHandle = $sftp->open($remoteFile, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT) or die($sftp->error());
my $tran = 0;
my $t = gettimeofday();
while(my $line = <$localHandle>)
{
  print $remoteHandle $line;
  $tran += length($line);
  my $newTime = gettimeofday();
  if($newTime - $t > 1)
  {
    print 'Speed is ' . ($tran / ($newTime - $t)) . "B/sec\n";
    $t = $newTime;
    $tran = 0;
  }
}
close($remoteHandle);
close($localHandle);
```

Comment: What kind of network links are between you and this server that you're sending the file to? The file transfer is only going to be as fast as the slowest link. You could also be running into QoS (quality of service) issues or some kind of rate limiting.

Comment: Also, I don't know how much it'd help, but you should think about using `sysread()` to read the file in blocks, instead of reading it line-by-line.

Comment: The link runs at 5.0MB/s all day if I use sftp from the command line so I'm pretty sure it is this module. I'm not sure why it's so steady at 5 but that is how it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support for SFTP in `Net::SSH2/libssh2` is suboptimal.

Use `Net::SFTP::Foreign` instead (with the `Net::SSH2 backend Net::SFTP::Foreign::Backend::Net_SSH2` if you are on Windows).

Comment: hmmmm, although using Net::SSH2 backend appear to be very slow.